# How to use StartForeground for service android

Tags: android, service

I have a Main activity, which can start a service using this command

> ```
> startService(new Intent(Main.this, Myservice.class));
> ```

and Myservice class is like this

```
   public class Myservice extends Service {
private ShakeListener mShaker;
String startell;
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    //Something

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Do Something to detecting shake
            //Show my notification


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Stop Shake detection
            //stop notification


    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

and my applications works fine, but after about one hour, service stops automatically, i mean after about one hour shake detection dose not work any more. :(

I googled a bit and I found I should use StartForeground, but I didn't find how.

Now, how should I use StartForeground in my code?

Comment: Do you use `wakelock` for the time while your service is running?

Comment: No, how should I Use that ?

Answer (score 1):

Code to Acquire & Release Lock

//acquire wake lock in onCreate() Method

```
devicePowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

wakeLock = devicePowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
        if(wakeLock != null){
            if(wakeLock.isHeld() == false){
                wakeLock.acquire();
            }
        }
```

//release wake lock in onDestroy() Method

```
if (wakeLock != null) {
            if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
                wakeLock.release();
                wakeLock = null;
            }
}
```

Comment: pls let me know whether this is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start service by calling `startService` method. And go through this example, it will help you

[Sample Project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer)

Comment: I read that Project, but i did not figured out how to use that, can you show it on my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you service stop working because of your device going to sleep. If you want it to work in background all the time you can use [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) to prevent you device from sleeping, BUT this will significantly increase battery consumption, so be carefull with it.

EDIT: You can `set()` lock in `onCreate` methond of your `Service` and `release()` it in `onDestroy()`

Comment: That's a good way, but I dont want my application prevent phone from sleeping, also, may user sleep it's own phone, in that case app stop running. :( any other suggestion?

Comment: You can't listen for shakes while device is sleeping, it's simple impossible. But there are `WakeLock` type that allow user to turn off the screen, but leave CPU of your device and all processes enabled. So you may try it, but still, battery consuption will be higher. This is `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` type. You can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK